# fill jquery modal form field value with javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, modal-dialog

I am a newbie - and am trying to auto fill a modal field value with a variable when it is loaded for the user.  I have a hunch that I need to add .val() to the dialog box when loading, but not sure.  Currently I am trying to load the value like a standard form.  Thanks for any help you can give me on this-

**Button to activate the modal:**

```
<input type="button" id="reply_clicky" name="emailmessage" onClick="updateReplyName('{{email.sender}}')" value="Reply" >
```

**Form:**

```
<div id="reply_form" title="Send Message">
<form id="replyemailform" method="POST" action="/sendemailmessage" name="emailposting">

    <p>
        <label for="recipient">To:</label>
        <input type="text"   name="recipient" id="recipient">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="subject">Subject: </label>
        <input type="text"  name="subject" id="subject">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="content">Message: </label>
        <textarea  name="content" id ="content"  class="textarea" rows="4" style=""></textarea>
    </p>

</form>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#reply_form').dialog({   
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 375,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
            text: "Cancel",
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }},
        {
            text: "Submit",
            click: function() {
                $('#replyemailform').submit();
            }}
        ]
    });
    $('#reply_clicky').button().click(function(e){
        $('#reply_form').dialog('open');
    });


}); 

function updateReplyName(sender){
console.log("updateReplyName function fired");
document.getElementById('recipient').value = sender;
}
```

**Edit to contain DevlshOne's suggestion:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#reply_form').dialog({   
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 375,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [
        {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }},
    {
        text: "Submit",
        click: function() {
            $('#replyemailform').submit();
        }}
    ]
});


$('#reply_clicky').button().click(function(e){
    $('#reply_form').dialog({
        open: function(e, ui) {
            $('#recipient').val('value is here');
        }
    });
    $('#reply_form').dialog('open');
});
});
```

Comment: Where is `sender` being assigned a value?

Comment: My thought was to pass {{email.sender}} to the updateReplyName function with {{email.sender}} as a parameter...naming it "sender"...maybe I didn't pass that in correctly?

Comment: As long as `sender` is assigned before you open the dialog, you can use the answer I posted below.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this, DevlshOne-  I added your suggested code, but now getting a syntax error "SyntaxError: missing } after property list".  (See edited code above) What do you think? -thanks

Comment: Try that, instead... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#reply_clicky').button().click(function(e){
    $('#reply_form').dialog({
        open: function(e, ui) {
            $('#recipient').val(sender);
        })
    });
    $('#reply_form').dialog('open');
});
```